# SSRS - Sort by Colors

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, colors

I am trying to sort a column in SSRS by the Font Color of that column, but am unable to grasp how... The color code that I have developed works as such.

```
=Switch(Fields!Prk_name.Value = "Lot 1", "DarkGoldenrod",
        Fields!Emp_default.Value = "L" OR Fields!Emp_default.Value = "B", "Black",
        Fields!Emp_default.Value = "C" AND Fields!Perm_prk.Value = "Y", "Green",
        Fields!Emp_default.Value = "C", "Purple")
```

What I was think of running under the SortExpression is this:

```
=Switch(Fields!Name.Color = "DarkGoldenrod" SortExpression (),
        Fields!Name.Color = "Black" SortExpression (),
```

So on and so forth just don't know what to put for SortExpression? I would need a way to sort for all 4 color types the base form of this is group by color then sort ABC.

Chris Lätta's post gave me an idea I gave that a try still does not work, but it might help to narrow down what I am looking for.

```
=Switch(Fields!Name.Color = "Darkgoldenrod", 1,
    Fields!Name.Color = "Purple", 2,
    Fields!Name.Color = "Black", 3,
    Fields!Name.Color = "Green", 4,
    True, 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort by a number as your first sort expression:

```
=Switch(Fields!Prk_name.Value = "Lot 1", 1,
    Fields!Emp_default.Value = "L" OR Fields!Emp_default.Value = "B", 2,
    Fields!Emp_default.Value = "C" AND Fields!Perm_prk.Value = "Y", 3,
    Fields!Emp_default.Value = "C", 4,
    True, 5)
```

then add another sort criteria to sort by the ABC column.

Comment: This did not work, still does not sort based on the Font color.

Comment: Would it be possible to do the ORDER BY Column.Color or something like this in Dataset query?